# How to access state from another composable in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to access state from another composable in jetpack compose? Want to access state from another composable.

```
@Composable
fun MySwitch() {
  val checkedState = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
  Switch(
    checked = checkedState.value,
    onCheckedChange = { checkedState.value = it }
  )
}

@Composable
fun MyUi() {
  MySwitch()
  Text(
    text = if(checkedState) "foo" else "bar",
  )
}
```

Comment: You have to hoist the state - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it actually depends on your situation i could give you 3 ways to do it:

**if you just have one switch and one text:**

```
[kotlin]
        @Composable
        fun MySwitch(checkedState: MutableState<Boolean>) {
          Switch(
            checked = checkedState.value,
            onCheckedChange = { checkedState.value = it }
          )
        }
        
        @Composable
        fun MyUi() {
        val checkedState = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
          MySwitch(checkedState = checkedState)
          Text(
            text = if(checkedState.value) "foo" else "bar",
          )
        }
```

**if you have multiple switchs and texts associated to them:**

```
@Composable
fun MySwitch() {
  val checkedState = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
  Switch(
    checked = checkedState.value,
    onCheckedChange = { checkedState.value = it }
  )
Text(
    text = if(checkedState.value) "foo" else "bar",
  )
}

@Composable
fun MyUi() {
  MySwitch()
MySwitch()
MySwitch()
}
```

**if you know MVVM and need this checked in your logic for exemple you have a database of To Do tasks then you well have this state(prefelably StateFlow) in your viewModel logic**