# How to Access State From Another Screen in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to access state from another screen in Jetpack Compose? I want to access state from another screen. How to access state?

```
@Composable
fun NavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "screen1"
    ) {
        composable(route = "screen1") {
            Screen1(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = "screen2") {
            Screen2(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen1(navController: NavHostController) {
    var index by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    Button(onClick = {
        navController.navigate(route = "screen2")
    }) {
        Text(text = "Screen1 $index")
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen2(navController: NavHostController) {
    Button(onClick = { index++ }) {
        Text(text = "Screen2")
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to hoist the state to the parent of both the composables.

Comment: For data sharing across navigation destinations, you can either pass the data as a parameter to the screen required or use a Shared ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76466617/19954200) that i made should help you you just have to adjust the code to what suits you.

Comment: Considering adding the actual answer to the OP's question as Link-only answers may be removed as Stack Overflow doesn't recommend this. [For reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)